# Access-Control-Allow-Origin blocked when wildcard is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have borrowed a library, [sessionTimeout](https://github.com/travishorn/jquery-sessionTimeout/blob/master/jquery.sessionTimeout.js), to build a standard "You will be automatically signed out, would you like to stay signed in?" dialog box.

The issue is with the keepAliveUrl.  We use an STS system on another site.  (I have control of both if need be).  The boss said that the keepAliveUrl should reference a .png file that is only accessible when logged in.  Doing so should refresh the token (he says).  Unfortunately, I have been running into the issue below when using IE.  Chrome seems to have no issue with it, but IE11 does.

Error below:

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://OtherSite/lock.png required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SEC7120: Origin https://MySite not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

I have looked into CORS quite a bit, and it sounds like the only thing we should need to allow the access is

```
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
```

In the STS server's web.config.

Here are the chrome request and response headers in case they offer more insight:

General

```
Request URL:https://OtherSite/lock.png
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

Response Headers

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:616
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Tue, 19 Apr 2016 21:19:34 GMT
ETag:"752713b2a791d11:0"
Last-Modified:Fri, 08 Apr 2016 15:02:40 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:*/*
Origin:https://MySite
Referer:https://MySite/TranscriptPortal/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36
```

***The question:***  How or what does this mean?  The wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin ***should*** let every request through.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly I did not.  Good luck!